# How to load the image from the site to a folder using Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

The application get the url of the image from the JSON file on Android.  After that, there is asynchronous loading of the image.

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage

class PicturesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = self.root
        image = AsyncImage(source='http:// site.com/test.jpg')
        root.add_widget(image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PicturesApp().run()
```

How can I save this image in a folder on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use *urlopen* or *requests* to download it in the first place and  and use the saved file as the source of the kivy Image